# Load more data from API when user scrolls the the page. REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, react-hooks, web-development-server

I am trying to complete this challenge from frontend mentor. I will be going to use React for completing this product.

> https://www.frontendmentor.io/challenges/rest-countries-api-with-color-theme-switcher-5cacc469fec04111f7b848ca

In this challenge I will be going to use this API

> https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all

I found a solution of other person.

> https://rest-countries-api-with-colour-theme-switcher.vercel.app/

I am also trying to create same but one thing that I specially want is that **I don't want to load all countries data at once** from the API. I want to initially load only data of 20-30 countries from the API and when **user scrolls to the bottom of page then I want to load more data**.

I searched over the internet but was not able to figure this out.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

So, there's a few steps to achieve this. And I'm assuming the API you provided doesn't have pagination capability.

- First store the api data in a state, e.g *'allData'*
- Then create another state for the filtered data based on scroll events. e.g *'filteredData'*
- *'filteredData'* will be the source of list in the UI.
- Add event listener for the scroll event to check if the scroll is at the bottom of the page and put it inside a lifecycle method/hook.

e.g:

```
useEffect(() => {
  function handleScrollEvent() {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
       console.log("you're at the bottom of the page");
       // here add more items in the 'filteredData' state from the 'allData' state source.
    }
 
  }

  window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScrollEvent)

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScrollEvent);
  }
}, [])
```

This should cover the flow you want to achieve :)